# Upgrading a simple drupal 7 module to drupal 8?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-8

I am new to drupal and currently using version 8. I am trying to convert cricket feed widget module in drupal 7 to drupal 8 based on community  [Instructions.](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/converting-drupal-7-modules-to-drupal-8). But I am unable to understand the routing.yml files. I don't understand the parameters used in the routing.yml file to connect with the controllers. I checked out some of their [examples.](https://www.drupal.org/node/2282025)

I don't understand

- what they mean by sub_name and
- Path: Path to the page on site.How do I know that?

Is it that much difficult to convert a simple drupal 7 module to drupal 8?

Comment: page_example module from drupal examples is pretty clear about how you should use the routing. As for complexity of upgrade it really depends on your components. If this module already exists in drupal.org or if not but you want to(aka make it open) I can help you with that.

Comment: Use backup and migrate module for datas , and you news to rewrite custom code to standard D8